# Magento: Sort getCrossSellProducts

Tags: magento

I am trying to display the cross sell product on a magento product oagei get the cross sell products like this

```
 $_crossSellProducts = $_product->getCrossSellProducts();
  if($_crossSellProducts):
   foreach ($_crossSellProducts as $_item):
    $_item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId());
```

I need to be able to sort the cross sell items by position. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

knowzero,you cant sort crossell products by position because of position depends on category.product of same category may sort by postion

Comment: by position, i mean the cross sell position in the parent product. for each cross sell item on product x I can put in a sort position.